# kivy Error when trying to add a button on gridlayot in a different class

Tags: python, class, layout, kivy, scrollview

My app wants to make a list from the strings typed in the `TextInput` field and show them in the `gridlayout` in the middle of the window after pressing the button `"Buscar"`. I'm sharing variables and functions between classes but when i try to add a new button with the `TextInput.text` inside the `gridlayout` shows the error message:

```
"AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'add_widget'"
```

Thank you

[The interface looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNTrS.png)

This is my .py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

class Lista(ScrollView):
    lista_repuestos = ObjectProperty()

class CustomWidget(FloatLayout):
    campo_de_busqueda_text_input = ObjectProperty()
    repuesto = StringProperty('')

    def submit_repuesto(self):
        self.repuesto = self.campo_de_busqueda_text_input.text
        Lista.lista_repuestos.add_widget(Button(text=self.repuesto))


class CustomWidgetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CustomWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CustomWidgetApp().run()
```

this is my .kv file

```
CustomWidget:

<CustomWidget>:

    campo_de_busqueda_text_input: campodebusqueda

    TextInput:
        id: campodebusqueda
        size_hint: .7, .1
        pos_hint: {"x": .15, "y": .85}

    Button:
        on_release: root.submit_repuesto()
        size_hint: .1, .1
        pos_hint: {"x": .85, "y": .85}
        text: "Buscar"

    Label:
        size_hint: .15, .05
        pos_hint: {"x": .05, "y": .15}
        text: "Descripción"
        text_size: self.size
        halign: "left"
    Label:
        size_hint: .15, .05
        pos_hint: {"x": .05, "y": .10}
        text: "Referencia"
        text_size: self.size
        halign: "left"
    Label:
        size_hint: .15, .05
        pos_hint: {"x": .05, "y": .05}
        text: "Cantidad"
        text_size: self.size
        halign: "left"


<Lista>:

    lista_repuestos: listarepuestos

    GridLayout:

        id: listarepuestos
        size_hint: .7, .6
        pos_hint: {"x": .15, "y": .25}
        cols: 1
        row_default_height: 50
        row_force_default: True
        padding: 5
        height: self.minimum_height
        size_hint_y: None
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line in the `CustomWidget`:

```
Lista.lista_repuestos.add_widget(Button(text=self.repuesto))
```

should reference an instance of `Lista`, not the class itself.

Comment: Hi John, `Lista` is the class, and `lista_repuestos` is the instance, Am I wrong?

Comment: `Lista` is the class. And `lista_repuestos` is the `ObjectProperty` that will be the `GridLayout` inside an instance of `Lista`. But it will not reference that `GridLayout` until an instance of `Lista` is created. I don't see anywhere in your Python code or your 'kv' file where any instance of `Lista` is created.

Comment: Also, the `CustomWidget:` line in your `kv` file does nothing, since your create the `CustomWidget` in the `build` method of your app.